# select into outfile : Headers not on top

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have done

```
select 'Header1', 'Header2'...
union all
select * from TABLE where $conditions
into outfile 'c:/users/sf/desktop/output.csv'
fields terminated by ';'
lines terminated by '\n'
```

The problem is: The headers are not on top but almost at the bottom. Version is 10.1.34-MariaDB.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 'What am I doing wrong?' - nothing I can see but mariadb/mysql seems a bit flakey when selecting headers into outfile judging by some quick googling.

Comment: A guess:  A `SELECT` generates an unordered list of rows unless you provide `ORDER BY`.  However, there is no practical way to do that for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rick_James has suggested, the select is unordered because no overal ordering is present. It can be solved like so:

```
select * from (
select '0Header1', 'Header2'...
union all
select * from TABLE where $conditions ) foo
order by 1
into outfile 'c:/users/sf/desktop/output.csv'
fields terminated by ';'
lines terminated by '\n'
```

provided the contents of the first row are all alphabetically after than '0Header1'.